# AWS Lightsail Wordpress Multisite - Elastic IP not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

When creating an AWS Lightsail instance with the Wordpress Multisite preset,
upon visiting the public ip it shows up as expected.

However, as soon as I attach a static ip to it and try to visit it in the browser,
it keeps loading infinitely.

Why is that?

My firewall settings are at the default value, so I have port 22, 80, and 443 open.

Thanks!

Comment: did you resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you [created a DNS Zone for your lightsail server](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry), to point at the IP you attached to the instance?

You may then need to [set the primary domain for your wordpress multisite](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-define-the-primary-domain-for-your-wordpress-multisite)

If that doesn't work, mine took about 20 minutes to propagate the DNS zone, but I suppose it could take longer.

Comment: Aren't DNS zones used for resolving domain names? In the current step, I'm still trying to attach an Elastic IP address.

Comment: @OhMad yes DNS zones are used for resolving domain names. I didn't parse that you were trying to visit the IP directly. My next guess would have been that the IP address change may not have propagated, but now that it's been 24 hours I'd have expected it to have. Can you ping the IP address in your command prompt with ping x.x.x.x ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the Static IP allocation for WP Multisite, connect to your instance using the SSH prompt an type in the following command:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/configure_app_domain --domain <StaticIP>
```

Source https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-quick-start-guide-wordpress-multisite#amazon-lightsail-attach-static-ip-wordpress-multisite